# Trigger a Matillion ETL Job from Airflow using SqsPublishOperator

Tags: python, airflow

From within Airflow I would like trigger an ETL Job to run in Matillion by publishing to an SQS queue we have set up in AWS.

On running the code below in Airflow I get the below error:

Error Invalid type for parameter

```
import os
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.sqs import SqsPublishOperator
from common.util import configuration, alerting

dag_id =  os.path.basename(__file__).replace(".py", "")
config = configuration.get_config(f'{dag_id}.yml')

# SQS queue to publish to in AWS
sqs_queue_name = 'run-etl-jobs'

args = {
          "ENVIRONMENT":  "dev",
          "account_name": "mydevaccount",
          "group": "Matillion_ETL_DEV",
          "project": "General"
          }

with DAG(dag_id=dag_id, **config['airflow'],
        on_failure_callback = opsgenie_alert.create_alert) as dag:
        start_task = DummyOperator(task_id='start')
        end_task = DummyOperator(task_id='end')

    publish_to_queue = SqsPublishOperator(
    task_id="publish_to_queue",
    sqs_queue=sqs_queue_name,
    message_content={
        "group":       args['group'],
        "project":     args['project'],
        "version":     "default",
        "environment": args['account_name'],
        "job":         "Matillion ETL Job",
        }
    )

    start_task >> publish_to_queue >> end_task
```

Comment: Could you please add the full error with its trace? Wild guess based on the [SqsPublishOperator source code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/operators/sqs.py): does it work if you provide the message content as a string and the message attributes json to `message_attributes` instead?